# What is the difference between the Life that Christ gives and the Life that Wisdom brings?

Tags: life-of-jesus, wisdom

I noticed that these two passages are rather similar:

> **Proverbs 8:35-36** (ESV)
> For whoever finds me [wisdom] finds life and obtains favor
> from the Lord, 36 but he who fails to find me injures himself; all who
> hate me love death.”
>
> **1 John 5:12** (ESV)
> Whoever has the Son has life; whoever does not have the Son of God
> does not have life.

What kind of `life` is being taught about in these two passages? Are they the same thing or how are they different?

Do any church doctrines speak directly to the issue of these two usages of `life`?

Comment: Related on Hermeneutics.SE: [What is the difference between the 'life' given by wisdom in Proverbs and 'life' given by Jesus in 1 John?](http://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/q/297)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The hebrew word for life in Proverbs is [chay](http://concordances.org/hebrew/2416.htm) (חָי) and means life or alive (which doesn't seem to imply anything spiritual).

In 1 John the word used is the greek word [zóé](http://concordances.org/greek/2222.htm) (ζωήν) which means: life, both of physical (present) and of spiritual (particularly future) existence.

So in the literal sense the verse 1 John is talking about more than just physical life, true spritual life. True spiritual life wasn't something that was possible prior to Jesus.

In a less literal sense they are both talking about the same thing and that is that true life is only found in God.